# more than one list item in each list activity?

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have a program that I would like to display the name and house number of a group of people. This information is being picked up from a web server and is all sorted (xml format) but I wanted it to be displayed in a ListView with the two different pieces of information in a single list item. When getting the information from the server there may be 3 people there may be 30 so a list view where it extends with the amount of information there is is essential. Any ideas?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a ListView and set your own customized ListAdapter that will display the two pieces of information you need in a single list item

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) it allows you to have custom "sub-data" under each list item.